# bibtex problems with absolute path name

Tags: bibtex

I have a problem running `bibtex` with absolute path filename, and this problem doesn't exist when I use a relative filename:

```
$ bibtex paper.aux
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2017/Debian)
The top-level auxiliary file: paper.aux
The style file: FOLDER_2_BIB_FILES/plain.bst
Database file #1: FOLDER_2_BIB_FILES/paper.bib
```

When I use an absolute filename (that comes from a makefile) everything goes wrong:

```
$ bibtex /home/oren/GIT/sqzComp/FOLDER_1_WRITEUP/paper.aux

bibtex: Not writing to /home/oren/GIT/sqzComp/FOLDER_1_WRITEUP/paper.blg (openout_any = p).
I couldn't open file name `/home/oren/GIT/sqzComp/FOLDER_1_WRITEUP/paper.blg'
```

Any way around this? I would hate touching the makefile itself. Thanks!

Comment: the default security settings prevent texlive programs writing to an absolute file path, or a relative one starting `../` you can turn that off in texmf.cnf and allow it to write anywhere but there are risks in doing that.

Comment: I would say your makefile is wrong, if you can't just do `bibtex paper`  then it has set up the wrong current directory.